# Python- Removing brackets from a list of results

Tags: python, mysql

i am retrieving some results from a mysql database and they come in a form separated by brackets. I want to remove the brackets, i have used the strip function but that will only work for when i have one result to display.

The code below will only remove brackets for search results that only have one element.

```
@QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_pushButton_clicked()")
def searchDBnumber(self):
    searchName = self.searchInput.toPlainText() 

    if len(searchName) != 0:
        searchForName = ("""SELECT number FROM test_table WHERE name =""" + "'"+ searchName +"'")



        cursor.execute(searchForName)

        result = cursor.fetchall()

        result = str(result).strip('[](),')
        self.number.setPlainText(result)
```

Comment: Try: `', '.join(map(repr, result))`. Can include the output of `print(result)` in your question?

Comment: Don't ever do this: `name =""" + "'"+ searchName +"'"` when forming SQL queries. Here lies the path to [lil Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use placeholders and pass your arguments to `cursor.execute`.

Comment: About "the form", `fetchall` returns a list of tuples (usually). You should format that using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (for example) to suit your needs, as pointed out by @MYGz.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple way is using **extend**

```
result = []
for i in c.fetchall()
    result.extend(i)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around I found that the results you get back from a mysql query aren't string but tuples so simply trying to remove the brackets doesn't work.

Here's is my example of how I dealt with it, starting with the query:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name1, name2 FROM testdatabase where (name1 REGEXP '^test.*') ")
```

I can then loop through the results and print each one like this:

```
for result in query_results:
    print(result)
```

Which gives some results like this:

```
('test0', 'something0')
('test1', 'something1')
('testing0', 'somethingelse1')
```

But I wanted to separate each of those results into both fields so you can do something like this:

```
for result in query_results:
    part1, part2 = result
    print('{} - {}'.format(part1, part2))
```

which will give you output like this:

```
test0 - something0
test1 - something1
testing0 - somethingelse1
```

Rather than just printing these out the plan for my code is to create a json type dictionary that I can easily search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply remove all brackets from a result, you can use replace() method. The syntax is string.replace(string_to_replace, string_to_replace_with).

eg:

```
result = str(result).replace("()", "")
```

This will need to be done for each bracket type, I believe. So another round for "[]".

Note that after you remove all brackets, splitting a result set to individual rows might be hard if the brackets are the delimiters.